# cannot find html pages with spring boot

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am using spring boot and angular in front end. Sometimes I want to redirect directly from a service. We are using only .html, .css and script files (no .jsp).

This is `return "static/pages/savepassword.html";` how I tried to redirect to savepassword

**So 1st question how do I redirect properly in this case?**

Next, Spring doesn't find my html files. I have this structure

[image]

I read that spring should find all static files in "static" automatically, but it doesn't. So I tried to configure my ViewControllerRegistry and RessourceControllerRegistry

```
@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
//      registry.addResourceHandler("/stylesheets/**").addResourceLocations("/stylesheets/");
//      registry.addResourceHandler("/scripts/**").addResourceLocations("/scripts/");
//      registry.addResourceHandler("/pages/**").addResourceLocations("/pages/");
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        super.addViewControllers(registry);
        registry.addViewController("/savePassword").setViewName("static/pages/savePassword.html");
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("static/pages/login.html");
        registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    }
```

When I call "static/pages/login.html" directly, it works. When i want to call "/login" it says 404.
**2nd question: What do I need to configure and what not?**

**UPDATE-1: Spring Security**

```
http
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login", "/logout", "/user/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedHandler(new CustomAccessDeniedHandler())
            .authenticationEntryPoint(new CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint())
        .and()
            .requiresChannel()
            .anyRequest().requiresSecure()
        .and()
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            //.csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())
            .addFilterBefore(new MDCFilter(), ExceptionTranslationFilter.class)
            // .addFilterBefore(new CorsFilter(),// ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
            //.addFilterAfter(new CsrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
            .formLogin()
            .successHandler(new CustomSuccessAuthenticationHandler())
            .failureHandler(new CustomFailureHandler())
            .loginPage("/login").permitAll();
```

**UPDATE-2**
I updated my structure, but still have problems with redirecting from /login to the custom login.
[image]

**UPDATE-3**
I had a look at the 2nd comment by Bob Shields: https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot
I did the following:

```
@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        super.addViewControllers(registry);
        registry.addViewController("/savepassword").setViewName("savepassword.html");
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login.html");
        registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    }
```

I set .html because otherwise /login would cause recursive problems. With this config, I can enter /login and /templates/login.html will be called (same for savepassword.html).

Now, **I would like to know how to include my css/js in html**:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="..resources/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="..resources/scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="..resources/scripts/login.js"></script>
```

This doesn't work...but I cann call my scripts directly with /scripts/login.js.

Comment: Can you try with /login.html?

Comment: No, because default Spring Security page comes up. Regulary, our custom login.html (static/pages/login.html) should show up.

I updated my answer, so you can see the spring security config.

I thought that the `ViewControllerRegistry` resolves login to static/pages/login,html and would take this login page

Comment: Do I may need to put the static folder in src/main/ressource instead of putting in webapp?

Comment: Can you try putting one page directly under webapp folder and referencing it with /login.html?

Comment: I deactivated spring security, but cant access when putting an html file directly in "resources".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, now I totally got it. I try to be specific as possible.

**My final structure**

[image: structure]

**1. Static Ressources**

Spring has some default configuration where you can put your static ressources without configure it. You need to create those folders in **src/main/resources**

- /META-INF/resources/
- resources (yes, an additional resources folder in src/main/resources
- static
- public

Have a look [here in Spring Doku.](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot) For an example, check the 2nd comment by Bob Shields:

> After creating a bunch of "findme.txt" files, each of which had different "source-relative" path string inside, I found that the following locations can be fetched with "http://host/findme.txt" are:
>
> src/main/resources/public/findme.txt
>
> src/main/resources/static/findme.txt
>
> src/main/resources/resources/findme.txt - (yes, resources^2!)
>
> src/main/resources/findme.txt - not found!!

I placed my folder "scripts" and "stylesheets" in the static folder. When I want to include files from these folders in html, the source looks like `src="scripts/file.js"`because the files and folders in `static`are found directly rooted to `host/scripts/file.js`

**No ResourceHandlerRegistry was necessary for me!**

**2. View Controller**

I wanted to root my login.html to /login, savepassword.html to /savepassword and my index.html to /. Here is what I did:

```
registry.addViewController("/savepassword").setViewName("savepassword.html");
registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login.html");
registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("loggedin/index.html");
```

I set *.html because otherwise I had a problem that spring didn't know to differ between /login and the login(.html).
As you can see I placed the index.html in a different folder called "loggedin". This folder is right in my public-folder (found by Spring, see 1.). Why do I do this? Have a look at 3.

**3. Spring Security**

```
.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/stylesheets/**", "/scripts/**","/login", "/user/**").permitAll()
...omitted further configuration...
.loginPage("/login").permitAll();
```

First, I want that a user always has to be logged in before he can visit any other sites. So all ressources for loginpage must be available.

This piece of code makes every file in stylesheets and scripts accessible. Remember stylesheets and scripts-folder are placed in static. I had to set "/login" because of the custom loginpage.
Honestly I thought that the `.loginPage("/login").permitAll();`would grant access, but it doesn't. Without it Spring tries to access the "/login", but can't cause of no rights and then automatically redirects to login => ERR_TOO_MANDY_REDIRECTS.
"/user/**" is just for some of my services that every user can use.

As you can see, I don't give access to "loggedin"-folder, so that every visitor can enter files in "loggedin" only if he is loggedin ;)

**4. Redirecting**

I just marked my whole controller with @RequestController, which implements @ResponseBody. When I return a String like return `"redirect:/savepassword";`, Spring will set this as ResponseBody and it will be interpreted as String/Json(?).

I had to mark the controller as @Controller and set @ResponseBody to every service that must return json or sth. My service that shall redirect was only marked with @RequestMapping and method=RequestMethod.GET. Finally, I return a String like `return "redirect:/savepassword";` This will make Spring redirect to /savepassword, which actually is placed in `src/main/resources/public/savepassword.html`.

**Finally, it works and it was hard enough to find how spring serves the files. I hope it helps someoneelse :)**

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion it is better to put your *.HTML files in your resources folder with all the static CSS FONTS and so on like in the picture below. In webapp you can have a WEB-INF folder only.

I am using this kind of structure and I have no problems finding any classes css or htmls and I do not use extensions at the end in java ("static/pages/login.html" like yours). If I want to access html I go like "user/someHtml" if it is in folder user for ex.

I know this answer is not precisely the one you are looking for but it may help you in someway.

[image]

**EDIT**: Now for the :

```
   @Override
   public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
       super.addViewControllers(registry);
       registry.addViewController("/savePassword").setViewName("static/pages/savePassword.html");
       registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("static/pages/login.html");
       registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
}
```

Lets say you have a Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/myController")
public class MyController{
...


@RequestMapping(value = "/login")
public String login(Model model) {
     // Your code ....

    return "login"; //<- this is your login.html if it is directly in resource/templates folder
}
    @RequestMapping(value = "/savePassword")
public String savePassword(Model model) {
     // Your code ....

    return "savePassword"; //<- this is your savePassword.html if it is directly in resource/templates folder
} 
.....
}
```

Now your **addViewController** show look like this :

```
   @Override
      public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
          super.addViewControllers(registry);
          registry.addViewController("/savePassword").setViewName("forward:/myController/savePassword");
       registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("forward:/myController/login");
       registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
}
```

You see in your **addViewController** you are trying to access a CONTROLLER not a HTML you will access your HTML through the CONTROLLER you access from the method **addViewControllers**.

**UPDATE:**

If you put your CSS into your static folder in resources like :

[image]

You can simply access them like this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css}" />
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: First, thank you ;) Yeah, i changed my structure like this, now (so +1), but yeah there are still the two questions: how to redirect and set ViewController.

Comment: Well I suppose you extend WebMvcConfigurerAdapter. So for ex. here is how when you try to access your app in the browser like http://localhost:8080/ you will be redirected to "user/showSomething" 



                                         @Override
    public void addViewControllers( ViewControllerRegistry registry ) {
        registry.addViewController( "/" ).setViewName("forward:/user/showSomething" );
        registry.setOrder( Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE );
        super.addViewControllers( registry );
    }


PS: You are missing maybe "forward" like in my ex. Hope this helps.

Comment: It just doesn't work...cant access any html...even without spring security and wihtout ViewControllerRegistry/ ResourceHandlerRegistry

Comment: Thanks, I did it a bit different to you. I have a problem now by including css and js... (see update 3)

Comment: Have you tried Jhipster? Have a look at it, it could be all you need.

Comment: I may found the problem. I annotated my controller with `@RestController` which implements `@RestBody`. When I call a service thats mapped by `@RequestMapping`, spring automatically sets the return value to `@ResponseBody`. Did I got the `@RestController` right?

My question would be: How can I override the `@ResponseBody`, which is automatically, internally set by `@RestController`, for one service?

Comment: And did you try annotating a controller with Controller , not with RestController ? Cause you may not need to override ResponseBody.