# Spring Boot - Proper location for html files

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am new to Spring Boot and I am trying to add a simple html page for my project
At the moment, my project's structure is the following:

[image]

Having read the following:
https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content

and other answers in StackOverflow, I'd expect to see the contents of index.html when I visit http://localhost:8080/

What could I be missing?

Comment: What could be missing? Your source code and the configuration properties if any - your [example], as well as the test against your server e.g. `http://localhost:8080` including output.

Answer (score 2):

As there is no webapp in SpringBoot project , we can place the html files in either in

```
src/main/resources/resources/index.html
src/main/resources/static/index.html 
src/main/resources/public/index.html
```

Remember the above is in highest to lowest precedence.

To check your file run the main class in eclipse and go to http://localhost:8080/index.html

Answer (score 1):

First of all the correct way to serve files in Spring Boot is described in
[cannot find html pages with spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35750114/cannot-find-html-pages-with-spring-boot?rq=1)

After adding the directories required, I tried `/services/login.html` where "services" is the mapping for my Dispatcher servlet.
So what happens here is that Spring Boot will only answer to requests sent to /services/* even if these requests are pointing to something other than a controller.
I guess that this makes sense in the world of Spring Boot but when I tried in the same in a Spring MVC project (no Spring Boot) I was able to access simple html files that I had simply added into my WEB-INF directory